# Pattern recognition for youtube

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Would [such question](https://superuser.com/questions/877415/pattern-recognition-for-youtube) could find place here?

> I am looking for software that would allow to match supplied image in
>   video frame. I plan to use it to data-mine Hearthstone videos to get
>   data on what decks are better.
>
> Couple of years ago I saw a guy (I think he's Ukrainian) to
>   demonstrate something similar. He would print screen live feed from
>   his web cam and then would cut part of image and then supply it to the
>   pattern recognition software he was running and it would apply border
>   on matching part on live feed while he was moving camera. It would
>   match it under certain angle. Since Hearthstone cards are always face
>   up it should be possible to reuse this. I tried looking for this video
>   and software without luck. If you know a peace of software that could
>   do something similar(with some tweaks perhaps) or other good idea how
>   to get my hands on Hearthstone game data please let me know.

Comment: You would have to try it to be certain, but I am personally clear that this would be wildly off-topic here. First, the statistical or machine learning content of this is minimal; at best it's about data acquisition (questions about getting datasets are off-topic here). Second, this is about software, and we have explicit advice that software-related questions are off-topic without a statistical core. Third, this  is based on rumour and anecdote so far as we are concerned. But the advice at http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic does imply all the key problems with this as a posting.

Comment: Although I agree w/ @NickCox that the quoted question would be off-topic on CV, *this* question (asking whether the quoted Q would be on topic on CV) *is* clearly on-topic for meta.CV. Discussing what might be on- or off-topic on the main site is definitely within the purview of the meta site.

Comment: Asking "is this kind of question on topic on CV" is clearly on topic on meta, even when the answer is "no"

Comment: Thanks guys, any idea where on SO this question would fit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the comments -- probably not. If you're asking about the pattern recognition software, there is a [StackExchange site for software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). If you're asking for where you could find game data, you could try the [Open Data StackExchange site](http://opendata.stackexchange.com), [the Hearthstone subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone), or even the [gaming StackExchange site](http://gaming.stackexchange.com).